# Number of arrangements in which no two persons sit side by side

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $10$ seats in the first row of the theater out of which $4$ are to be occupied. Find the number of ways of arranging $4$ people so that no two people sit side by side.

Making different cases would be very lengthy process. Is there any smarter way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**  Imagine that you have ten chairs.  Set out six empty chairs in a row, leaving spaces between them and at the ends of the row in which to place the four people.

$$\square c \square c \square c \square c \square c \square c \square$$

Choose four of those seven spaces in which to place the chairs of the four people, then arrange the people in those chosen spaces.

Comment: One question: We had removed four chairs..what about the different combinations of those four chairs that can be removed?

Comment: @Abcd You should think of the chairs as being identical.  It is the people in those chairs that matter.  Line up the people in some order, such as alphabetically.  The first person in line has a choice of seven places in which to place his/her chair, the second person is left with six such choices, the third person with five such choices, and the fourth person with four such choices.  Hence, there are $7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 = 840$ possible seating arrangements.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your reply. Also, what if the chairs were fixed? How would you remove those 4 chairs in that case? Sorry for so many questions , I am struggling with this question since 4 hours.

Comment: @Abcd In reality, the chairs are fixed.  This is an ad hoc method that allows you to circumvent using the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: Could we talk about this in a chat room? I'd be extremely grateful

Comment: @Abcd Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72006/discussion-between-abcd-and-n-f-taussig).

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

To be found first is the number of sums $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5=6$ where $n_1,n_5$ are nonnegative integers and $n_2,n_3,n_4$ are positive integers.

Interpret the $+$'s here as chairs that will be occupied. and the $n_i$ as numbers op open seats.

That comes to the same as finding the number of sums $m_1+m_2+m_3+m_4+m_5=3$ where the $m_i$ are nonnegative integers. For this you can use [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

After that the $4$ persons must be placed on the selected seats.

Comment: The number of open seats is $6$, not $10$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Yes, you are right. Thanks for correcting me. I repaired.

Answer (score 4):

Take out $3$ chairs, arrange the $4$ people in $\binom74\times 4!$ ways,
insert back the $3$ chairs immediately to the right of each seated person except the last.

Comment: what if the seats are fixed or numbered?

Comment: @Abcd: The seats *are* fixed or numbered. They are *imagined* initially as unnumbered and removable, and successively removed/replaced/numbered to easily get the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine an 11th seat at the left end; each person takes their own seat and the one on their left.
There are three other gaps, and the four people.

Comment: Can you elaborate last statement, "There are three other gaps, and the four people. " a bit more?

Comment: Eleven seats include four people; their four spare seats, and three other seats.  The four people must be next to their spare seats, so you arrange seven items in a row: four double seats and three single seats.